# Is it possible to alter the tag information on a Terraform API Gateway Domain Name resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, terraform, infrastructure

I am creating a Route53 URL which points to a CloudFront distribution and hits an API Gateway endpoint. I got the Terraform definitions to work and everything deployed correctly. However, I need to add tags to the CloudFront distribution.

Here is the relevant Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "api-gateway-domain" {
    domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
    certificate_arn = "${var.arn}
    count        = "${var.count}"
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "route53" {
    zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.route53-zone.zone_id}"
    name    = "${var.domain_name}"
    type    = "A"
    alias {
      name                   = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.api-gateway-domain.cloudfront_domain_name}"
      zone_id                = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.api-gateway-domain.cloudfront_zone_id}"
      evaluate_target_health = true
    }
    count   = "${var.count}"
}
```

I'm wondering if I can do something like `"${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.api-gateway-domain.cloudfront_domain_name.id.tags}" = { TAGS = "foobar" }` or something to that effect.

Is this possible? Or will I have to manually set up a CloudFront distribution to point my Route53 URL at?

Comment: It's not overly clear what you're trying to achieve here. Do you have a Cloudfront distribution in front of your API Gateway? API Gateway is backed by Cloudfront anyway but creating an API Gateway doesn't create a Cloudfront distribution resource in your AWS account.

Comment: According to the Terraform documentation on the aws_api_gateway_domain_name resource "Internally API Gateway creates a CloudFront distribution to route requests on the given hostname." (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_domain_name.html)
On the AWS documentation, "for every API you create, API Gateway sets up an Amazon CloudFront distribution for the API." (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html)

Terraform gives me access to the CloudFront distribution `domain_name` and `zone_id` through the `api_gateway_domain_name`.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot.

The CloudFront Distribution that API Gateway creates is *completely invisible* to you; you have no way of seeing it, no way of altering it. Really, the fact that they even tell you that's what it is and then give you some information such as the "Target Domain name" is incredibly confusing. It's the same as when they say "Instance store-backed AMIs are stored by S3" - But you don't have any access to the actual S3 object.

Also, no - you will not need to create your own CloudFront Distribution; however you should be able to point your Route53 record at the CloudFront Target Domain Name that shows up in the "Custom Domain Names" section of API Gateway.

Neither the [route53_record](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html) nor [api_gateway_domain_name](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_domain_name.html) support a Tag block; likely due to AWS not supporting tags on them (Which I know - crazy, considering AWS always says you should tag everything, but then doesn't provide the option to).

So you're just kinda SOL on being able to tag these resources; and it won't be the last time you run into this unfortunately.